# List every file and folder of a shared drive in a spreadsheet with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

I found a script that works flawlesly for My Drive that I want to adapt to also support Shared Drives.

```
    function onOpen() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('List Files/Folders')
    .addItem('List All Files and Folders', 'listFilesAndFolders')
    .addToUi();
};

function listFilesAndFolders(){
  var folderId = Browser.inputBox('Enter folder ID', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (folderId === "") {
    Browser.msgBox('Folder ID is invalid');
    return;
  }
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
  try {
    // Get folder by id
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    
    // Initialise the sheet
    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Name","Type" ,"Date", "URL", "Last Updated", "Description", "Size","Owner Email"]);
    
    // Get files and folders
    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
 
  // List folders inside the folder
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var folderId = childFolder.getId();
    data = [ 
      parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getName(),
      "Folder",
      childFolder.getDateCreated(),
      childFolder.getUrl(),
      childFolder.getLastUpdated(),
      childFolder.getDescription(),
      childFolder.getSize()/1024,
      childFolder.getOwner().getEmail()
    ];
    // Write
    sheet.appendRow(data);
    
    // List files inside the folder
    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      data = [ 
        parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getName(),
        "Files",
        childFile.getDateCreated(),
        childFile.getUrl(),
        childFile.getLastUpdated(),
        childFile.getDescription(),
        childFile.getSize()/1024,
        childFile.getOwner().getEmail(),
      ];
      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
    // Recursive call of the subfolder
    getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet, listAll);  
  }
};
```

I honestly still don't fully understand how

```
{supportsAllDrives: true}
```

works but I'll assume that it is exactly what's missing.

I've been trying to get some more information about it, but what I've found is't exactly useful for me and it's not a complete explanation on how to use it.

I'm very new to Apps Script but I'm doing my best to make fully operational code or at least understand it, so I would really appreciate if anyone could link me to any good pages  about it.

Comment: Did you try the suggested solutions?

Comment: Yes, I actually had answered to Tanaike, but the comment somehow got removed. His answer works except for owner email and there is an issue with the path of subfolders in subfolders because of how path is coded. The general code is fine but it is painfully slow to the point it would be unusable for more than 800 files especially if those are placed inside subfolders because of how it loops through folders and appendRow. I've made some considerable changes to get rid of unused code and to make it a lot faster. I will post the result and maybe even see if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: Well. It's important to accept the correct answers. This way everyone will see how the problem was solved (even partially). As for the rest, it makes sense to ask @Tanaike directly if there is a workaround. (If you add `@` before a nikname in your comment it will sent the comment to the mentioned member)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{supportsAllDrives: true}` is used for Drive API. But, fortunately, in the current stage, when the file ID and folder ID is used, the files and folders in the shared drive can be retrieved using Drive service (DriveApp). But unfortunately, the owner of files and folders cannot be retrieved. I thought that this might be the reason of your current issue of your showing script. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
data = [ 
  parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
  childFolder.getName(),
  "Folder",
  childFolder.getDateCreated(),
  childFolder.getUrl(),
  childFolder.getLastUpdated(),
  childFolder.getDescription(),
  childFolder.getSize()/1024,
  childFolder.getOwner().getEmail()
];
```

#### To:

```
var ownerOfFolder = childFolder.getOwner();
data = [ 
  parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
  childFolder.getName(),
  "Folder",
  childFolder.getDateCreated(),
  childFolder.getUrl(),
  childFolder.getLastUpdated(),
  childFolder.getDescription(),
  childFolder.getSize()/1024,
  ownerOfFolder ? ownerOfFolder.getEmail() : ""
];
```

And also, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
data = [ 
  parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
  childFile.getName(),
  "Files",
  childFile.getDateCreated(),
  childFile.getUrl(),
  childFile.getLastUpdated(),
  childFile.getDescription(),
  childFile.getSize()/1024,
  childFile.getOwner().getEmail(),
];
```

#### To:

```
var ownerOfFile = childFile.getOwner();
data = [ 
  parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
  childFile.getName(),
  "Files",
  childFile.getDateCreated(),
  childFile.getUrl(),
  childFile.getLastUpdated(),
  childFile.getDescription(),
  childFile.getSize()/1024,
  ownerOfFile ? ownerOfFile.getEmail() : "",
];
```

#### Note:

- When I tested your script reflected the above modification to the shared Drive, I could confirm that the script works.

Answer (score 1):

I have a function that copies the information to a sheet for me all it needs is a folder.  You can modify as you require:

Starting function:

```
function AddDataValidation(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');  
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder id");
  getFnF(folder);
}
```

The recursive function:

```
var level = 1;
function getFnF(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//active spreadsheet
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')//change sheet name
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, level).setValue(folder.getName()).setFontWeight('bold');
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, level).setValue('Files:');
  }
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let firg = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, level + 1);
    firg.setValue(Utilities.formatString(file.getName()));
  }
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    level++;
    getFnF(subfolder);
  }
  level--;
}
```

Folders in A Shared Drive:

Produces a table with Title, Id and Path

```
function getFoldersInASharedFolder() {
  let tr = [];
  let token = '';
  let page = 0;
  do {
    let r = Drive.Files.list({ corpora: 'drive', includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsTeamDrive: true, supportsAllDrives: true, driveId: "driveId", pageToken: token,q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'" });
    let obj = JSON.parse(r);
    tr.push(obj)
    token = obj.nextPageToken
  } while (token != null)

  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid);
  folder.createFile(`SharedDriveList ${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}`, JSON.stringify(tr), MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);

  let html = '<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;font-size: 16px;}</style><table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Id</th><th>Path</th></tr>';
  tr.forEach((o, i) => {
    o.items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder") {
        html += `<tr><td>${item.title}</td><td>${item.id}</td><td>${getPathAllDrivesFromId(item.id)}</td></tr>`;
      }
    })
  });
  html += '</table><input type="button" value="exit" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setHeight(500).setWidth(1200), `Folders in: ${JSON.parse(Drive.Drives.get("driveid")).name}`);
}
```

The below function will find all of your shared drives and create an indented tree for all files and folders.  It also selects and populate a sheet for each of the shared drive with file names and links to each folder and file.

```
function sharedDriveTrees() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.sharedssid);//need to change the ssid for the output spreadsheet
  const r = Drive.Drives.list();
  const drives = JSON.parse(r).items;
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter((sh, i) => i < drives.length).filter(e => e);
  var trees = [];
  drives.forEach((obj, i) => {
    obj["title"] = obj.name;
    let ob =JSON.parse(Drive.Files.get(obj.id,{ supportsAllDrives: true, supportsTeamDrives: true }));
    obj["alternateLink"] = ob.alternateLink;
    Logger.log('Drive Title: %s Time: %s', obj.title, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"));
    shts[i].setName(`${obj.title}\n${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")}`);
    let tree = [];
    CacheService.getScriptCache().put("tree", JSON.stringify(tree), 60);
    level = 1;
    gff(obj)
    tree = JSON.parse(CacheService.getScriptCache().get("tree"));
    let l = tree.reduce((a, c) => {
      if (c.length > a) {
        a = c.length;
      }
      return a;
    }, 0);
    tree.forEach((a, j) => {
      if ((l - a.length) > 0) {
        let arr = [...Array.from(new Array(l - a.length).keys(), x => "")];
        tree[j] = a.concat(arr);
      }
    });
    trees.push(tree);
    const sh = shts[i];
    sh.clearContents();
    sh.getRange(1, 1, tree.length, tree[0].length).setValues(tree);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  });
}

level = 1;
function gff(fobj) {
  //Logger.log('Drive Title: %s', fobj.title);
  const r = Drive.Children.list(fobj.id);
  const fldrMime = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
  let tree = JSON.parse(CacheService.getScriptCache().get("tree"));
  let files = [];
  let subfolders = [];
  fobj["level"] = level;
  let children = JSON.parse(r).items;
  children.forEach((obj, i) => {
    let o = JSON.parse(Drive.Files.get(obj.id, { supportsAllDrives: true, supportsTeamDrives: true }));
    o["level"] = level;
    if (o.mimeType == fldrMime) {
      subfolders.push(o);
    } else {
      files.push(o);
    }
  });
  //Logger.log('level: %s', level);
  let arr1 = [...Array.from(new Array(level).keys(), x => { if (x < (level - 1)) { return '' } else { return `=HYPERLINK("${fobj.alternateLink}","${fobj.title}")` } })];
  //Logger.log('arr1: %s', JSON.stringify(arr1));
  tree.push(arr1)
  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    files.forEach(obj => {
      let arr2 = [...Array.from(new Array(level + 1).keys(), x => { if (x < (level)) { return '' } else { return `=HYPERLINK("${obj.alternateLink}","${obj.title}")` } })];
      //Logger.log('arr2: %s', JSON.stringify(arr2));
      tree.push(arr2)
    })
  }
  CacheService.getScriptCache().put("tree", JSON.stringify(tree), 60);
  subfolders.forEach(obj => {
    level++;
    obj.level = level;
    CacheService.getScriptCache().put("tree", JSON.stringify(tree), 60);
    gff(obj);
    tree = JSON.parse(CacheService.getScriptCache().get("tree"))
  });
  level--;
  return;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Cooper, thanks it works very well for me. One small question. How can I add last modified date into the next column?