# I don't want to list all subfolders in gdrive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm using this script on AppScript in google sheets to list all the folders in a shared folder, however, I don't want to list all the subfolders.

Ideally, I'd like the program to only lookup 2 level of subfolders before stopping. In other words, I'd like all the folders in the folders in the parent folder to be listed.

If that's not possible, it would be preferable to only list the folders in the parent folder.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here's my current code:

```
function onOpen() {     
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();                      
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()                              
.createMenu('Custom Scripts')                               
.addItem('List All Files and Folders', 'listFilesAndFolders')                       
.addToUi();         
}
                    
function listFilesAndFolders(){
  var folderId = Browser.inputBox('Enter folder ID', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (folderId === "") {
    Browser.msgBox('Folder ID is invalid');
    return;
  }
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
  try {
    // Get folder by id
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    
    // Initialise the sheet
    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Name","Type" ,"Date", "URL", "Last Updated", "Description", "Size","Owner Email"]);
    
    // Get files and folders
    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
 
  // List folders inside the folder
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var folderId = childFolder.getId();
    data = [ 
      parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getName(),
      "Folder",
      childFolder.getDateCreated(),
      childFolder.getUrl(),
      childFolder.getLastUpdated(),
      childFolder.getDescription(),
      childFolder.getSize()/1024,
      childFolder.getOwner().getEmail()
    ];
    // Write
    sheet.appendRow(data);
    
    // List files inside the folder
    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      data = [ 
        parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getName(),
        "Files",
        childFile.getDateCreated(),
        childFile.getUrl(),
        childFile.getLastUpdated(),
        childFile.getDescription(),
        childFile.getSize()/1024,
        childFile.getOwner().getEmail(),
      ];
      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
    // Recursive call of the subfolder
    getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet, listAll);  
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What have you tried to achieve limit the script to 2 level of subfolders?

Comment: You can use a recursive function.  You can monitor the levels and exit the function when two levels are achieved the function will continue running if there are addittion subfolders below level two

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71270825/7215091