# How to create a list of all folders in a shared goggle drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to create a  listing of all my google drive folders and I have the following script and a link to the question where I got the script from. I'm just not sure how to implement it. I put the Drive ID in line 6 and then ran it and got this error; Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

[List every file and folder of a shared drive in a spreadsheet with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71270142/list-every-file-and-folder-of-a-shared-drive-in-a-spreadsheet-with-apps-script)

11:08:37 AM Error
ReferenceError: gobj is not defined
getFoldersInASharedFolder   @ Folder Listing.gs:12

This is the script

```
function getFoldersInASharedFolder() {
  let tr = [];
  let token = '';
  let page = 0;
  do {
    let r = Drive.Files.list({ corpora: 'drive', includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsTeamDrive: true, supportsAllDrives: true, driveId: "???", pageToken: token,q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'" });
    let obj = JSON.parse(r);
    tr.push(obj)
    token = obj.nextPageToken
  } while (token != null)

  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid);
  folder.createFile(`SharedDriveList ${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}`, JSON.stringify(tr), MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);

  let html = '<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;font-size: 16px;}</style><table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Id</th><th>Path</th></tr>';
  tr.forEach((o, i) => {
    o.items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder") {
        html += `<tr><td>${item.title}</td><td>${item.id}</td><td>${getPathAllDrivesFromId(item.id)}</td></tr>`;
      }
    })
  });
  html += '</table><input type="button" value="exit" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setHeight(500).setWidth(1200), `Folders in: ${JSON.parse(Drive.Drives.get("driveid")).name}`);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message occurs because

```
let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid);
```

use the a nested property of `gobj` as parameter but `gobj` was not declared.

You can fix this error either by properly declaring `gobj` or by replacing  `gobj.globals.testfolderid` by the folder id (properly set as a string).

Comment: Thanks, Ruben - I will keep working on that. I'm just learning so I won't bother you anymore I will do some more research but thankyou for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

The comments explain how to use this function

```
function getFoldersInASharedFolder() {
  const sharedriveid = "";//add the shared drive id here
  const storagefilefolderid = ""; //this where I was storing the response which I used when I was first building the script. It's not necessary to do this if you don't wish to.  You can just comment that code out of the script
  let tr = [];
  let token = '';
  let page = 0;
  do {
    let r = Drive.Files.list({ corpora: 'drive', includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, supportsTeamDrive: true, supportsAllDrives: true, driveId: sharedriveid, pageToken: token,q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'" });//drive id for the shared drive that you wish all of the folders from
    let obj = JSON.parse(r);
    tr.push(obj)
    token = obj.nextPageToken
  } while (token != null)

  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(storagefilefolderid);//the folder id for the file that stores the results
  folder.createFile(`SharedDriveList ${Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}`, JSON.stringify(tr), MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);

  let html = '<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;font-size: 16px;}</style><table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Id</th><th>Path</th></tr>';
  tr.forEach((o, i) => {
    o.items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder") {
        html += `<tr><td>${item.title}</td><td>${item.id}</td><td>${getPathAllDrivesFromId(item.id)}</td></tr>`;
      }
    })
  });
  html += '</table><input type="button" value="exit" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setHeight(500).setWidth(1200), `Folders in: ${JSON.parse(Drive.Drives.get(sharedrivedid)).name}`);
}
```

Comment: I've re-read the comments on the original question - I don't see any further information. Can you explain please?