# List all files and folders from google drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, timeout

I want to list all files and folders from Google drive but i can't get past the Google Apps script maximum execution timer which stops around 6 minutes into the script.

I want the code to run every 1 minute while it continues from where it last stopped.

What piece of code should i add to my code to make it do that?

I would prefer something i can just copy paste.

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var searchMenuEntries = [{
        name: "Create List from Folder",
        functionName: "start"
    }];
    ss.addMenu("Document List", searchMenuEntries);
}


function start() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size", "URL", "Download", "Description", "Type", "Folder", "Folder Slug"]);

    var folderName = Browser.inputBox("Enter Folder Name (this will destroy the current spreadsheet):");
    //var folderName = "Safety Subdomain Assets";

    var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);

    if (folder.hasNext()) {
        processFolder(folder);
    } else {
        Browser.msgBox('Folder not found!');
    }


    function processFolder(folder) {
        while (folder.hasNext()) {
            var f = folder.next();
            var contents = f.getFiles();
            addFilesToSheet(contents, f);
            var subFolder = f.getFolders();
            processFolder(subFolder);
        }
    }

    function addFilesToSheet(files, folder) {
        var data;
        var folderName = folder.getName();
        while (files.hasNext()) {
            var file = files.next();
            Logger.log(file.getName());

            sheet.appendRow([
      file.getName(),
      file.getDateCreated(),
      file.getSize(),
      file.getUrl(),
      "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + file.getId(),
      file.getDescription(),
      file.getMimeType(),
      folderName
    ]);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74176523/7215091

Answer (score -1):

This will list all files and folders on to Sheet0 in a tree like fashion:

```
var level = 1;
function getFnF(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, level).setValue(folder.getName()).setFontWeight('bold');
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, level).setValue('Files:');
  }
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let firg = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, level + 1);
    firg.setValue(Utilities.formatString(file.getName()));
  }
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    level++;
    getFnF(subfolder);
  }
  level--;
}

function getFilesAndFolders() {
  const fldr = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet0').clearContents();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Entry');
  getFnF(fldr);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('EOF');
}
```

This might be a little faster because it stores everything in PropertiesService and then writes it all at one time.

```
function getFilesAndFolders() {
  const fldr = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet0').clearContents();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Entry');
  getFnF(fldr);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('EOF');
}

function getFnF1(folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder()) {
  let tree = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FnF'));
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(tree));
  if (tree.level < level) {
    tree.level = level;
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));
  }
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  let row = Array.from([...Array(level).keys()], ((x, i) => { if (i == level - 1) { x = folder.getName(); } else { x = ''; } return x; }));
  tree.txt.push(row);
  row = Array.from([...Array(level).keys()], ((x, i) => { if (i == level - 1) { x = 'bold'; } else { x = 'normal'; } return x; }));
  tree.fwt.push(row);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    let row = Array.from([...Array(level).keys()], ((x, i) => { if (i == level - 1) { x = 'Files:'; } else { x = ''; } return x; }));
    tree.txt.push(row);
    tree.fwt.push(['normal']);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));
  }
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let row = Array.from([...Array(level + 1).keys()], ((x, i) => { if (i == level) { x = file.getName(); } else { x = ''; } return x; }));
    tree.txt.push(row);
    tree.fwt.push(['normal']);
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify(tree));
  }
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    level++;
    getFnF1(subfolder);
  }
  level--;
}

function getFilesAndFolders1() {
  const fldr = null;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.toast("Entry");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.clearContents();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('FnF', JSON.stringify({ txt: [], fwt: [], level: 0 }));
  getFnF1();
  //Logger.log(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FnF'));
  let tree = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FnF'));
  const l = tree.level + 1
  tree.txt.forEach(r => {
    if (r.length < l) {
      //Array.from(Array(l - r.length).keys()).forEach(e => r.push(''));
      r.splice(r.length, 0, ...Array(l - r.length).fill(''));
    }
  });
  tree.fwt.forEach(r => {
    if (r.length < l) {
      //Array.from(Array(l - r.length).keys()).forEach(e => r.push('normal'));
      r.splice(r.length, 0, ...Array(l - r.length).fill('normal'));
    }
  });
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(tree));
  sh.getRange(1, 1, tree.txt.length, tree.level + 1).setValues(tree.txt);
  sh.getRange(1, 1, tree.fwt.length, tree.level + 1).setFontWeights(tree.fwt);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty('FnF');
  ss.toast("EOF");
}
```

Comment: The problem is not listing the files and folders, it is the timeout. After 5 minutes, it timesout. Also, where do i specify which folder to scan in your code?

Comment: You can get a paid account and it won't timeout.  I have about 3.24 GB and it takes about 13 minutes.  I doubt that you're going to get it much faster.  Writing it to the spreadsheet takes time.