# Google workspace services full example

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, drive

I can't find a fully, runnable example. It's always just the code itself.
I'm not even sure where I can run it.
There's examples how to run it in Sheets and such, but not for Google Drive.
I suppose I have to use one of the languages and run it locally? What's a full example that's executable to run Google workspace services code like DriveApp.

E. G. Let's take this following code https://stackoverflow.com/a/77115873/7215091
These are just a bunch of functions. You can't put them in a file and run them obviously.
How do I run this code?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result of `I want to list all files in my Google drive.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output values of your `list`? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: `But I can't find a fully, runnable example.` I don't understand the question. You want to list all the files on Google Drive. Would you describe **where** you would like to create/display the list; i.e. what is the output destination. Examples run in Sheets are generally because the output is to be displayed in sheets. I'm sorry if the question is more nuanced than my reading.

Comment: @Tanaike I don't need the code itself for listing files. It can be found here for example https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app
But I don't know how to run it. It's not fully runnable code.

Comment: @Tedinoz Actually I don't just want to list files. I just made this example. I want to run actions on files. There won't be any output needed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I don't need the code itself for listing files. It can be found here for example developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app But I don't know how to run it. It's not fully runnable code.`. You want to use Class DriveApp. But, you don't want to use a script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike コードそのものはいらない。コードを交換できる、完全に実行可能なサンプルが必要なだけです。

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `コードそのものはいらない。コードを交換できる、完全に実行可能なサンプルが必要なだけです。`, can I ask you about the details of `完全に実行可能なサンプル`?

Comment: Here's a recursive script that will create a spreadsheet of all files and folders.  It take about 18 minutes on my drive of  3.3 gb so depending upon your drive size and your  type of account it may timeout. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77115873/7215091)

Comment: Thanks but I think I need to somehow rewrite my question. I don't need the specific code, I need to know how to run it. But seems it doesn't come across.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems I really have to use Google Sheets or Google Forms to do this.
What I figured:

1. make a new empty sheet (or form)
2. go to Tools -> Script Editor
3. paste the code there like a function onOpen() will run when the sheet is opened or onSubmit when a form is submitted
   3.1. you can add a menu entry button in the onOpen() function in sheets
4. run the code by clicking the button in the sheets menu

source: https://hawksey.info/blog/2015/02/tutorial-interacting-with-your-google-drive-with-apps-script-including-parsingwriting-csv-files/

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, will do that at work tomorrow and mark the answer if it works as expected.